# Configuring iptables to use company web proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, iptables

It is possible to redirect incoming traffic on a linux machine (raspberry) to a webproxy with username/password using iptables?
I only found examples where traffic is redirected to a transparent proxy like squid...
In our company Internetaccess is only allowed using the company proxy server.
The story behind is, that our wifi controller should have access to the internet.
I would like to configure a static route on the wifi controller which sends traffic to a raspberry acting as gateway. Then the raspberry should redirect the traffic to our company proxy.

Comment: There should be no difference - the iptables are just redirecting the traffic, it shouldn't matter if it carries extra authentication. Or are you trying to hold the login information only on the machine with iptables and expect them to handle the authentication?

Comment: Yes, the machine which runs iptables should handle the authentication. I have no chance to configure any proxy settings on the the wifi controller.

Comment: you won't be able to do that with iptables alone then. What is the type of authentication? If it's HTTP Basic, it might be possible with packet editing by `netsed`. If it's oauth2, you can pretty much give up now. IMO: just give up on this now and save your precious time. Find a different solution, like wireless internet from phone company...